# What is happening when you press escape to exit fullscreen? How can I replicate it with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fullscreen

I am trying to add a fullscreen option for a JavaScript canvas game of mine, and it is functional across some browsers, but issues with Firefox have made me realize that my logic was very broken and it was lucky that it worked for any browser.

I want to have a button on the canvas that lets you toggle fullscreen, but I am running into a few issues. The first problem I found was that if I `canvas.getBoundingClientRect()` on resize (when I exit/enter fullscreen), then in certain browsers *cough Firefox*, the function runs too early and it gets the bounds *before* they have changed, so the game still thinks it should be huge.

You can check out the code and the program [here](http://jdhcodelab.com/test/gravity/). Let me know if I wasn't very clear on anything, this one has hard to explain.

Comment: you should almost always use a small timeout on resize events

Comment: Should that be on every resize function? Is there a way to do it on all at once?

Comment: look into the debounce pattern, which is good for scroll and resize. https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce it helps performance by avoiding hammering, but it will also fix your out-of-sync dom dimension sniffing.

Comment: Store the original width and height on game start and keep a bool variable so you know if the player has entered fullscreen or not, then when the player presses the esc key, check to see if the fullscreen bool is true, if it is then set the canvas back to the original width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Welcome to the [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) nightmare.**

This API is still in development and the specs have changed a lot since it first came out on the web.
Unfortunately, as of today, none of the major browsers do really support it <sub>(e.g actual specs recommend the use of promises)</sub> and even worse, none of those do use the same keywords for this API.

So it can be a bit harsh to make them all happy with it.

But first, you should not listen to the `resize` event, since it may occur multiple times during the activation/desactivation of the fullscreen mode.

What you need is the [`fullscreenchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/fullscreenchange) event.
Fortunately enough, every UA did write the whole event name without any camelCase in it, but with vendor prefixes. (and for some reason, IE doesn't support attaching it with `addEventListener` method...)

Once you get the event, in order to know if we actually entered or exited the fullscreen mode, you have to check for a [`document.[vendor-prefix]full(s||S)creenElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/mozFullScreenElement) if there is one, then we entered the mode ; else we exited it.

And now, to exit the fullscreen mode, you've got to call
[`document.[vendor-prefix]((e||E)xit||Cancel)(f||F)ull(s||S)creen`](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-exitfullscreen) method.

So here is a little **dirty** helper function for it :

```js
// if fullscreen API is supported it will return an array containing
// [vendor-prefix, 'full(s||S)creen', 'Exit||Cancel'];
var fs = function(){
    // if it is natively supported without vendor prefix (may it happen some day...)
    if('onfullscreenchange' in document){
        return ['', 'Fullscreen', 'exit'];
    }
    if('onmozfullscreenchange' in document){
        return ['moz','FullScreen', 'Cancel'];
    }
    if('onwebkitfullscreenchange' in document){
        return ['webkit', 'Fullscreen', 'Exit'];
    }
    if('onmsfullscreenchange' in document){
        return ['ms', 'Fullscreen', 'Exit'];
    }
}();


if(fs){
    // for some reason, IE doesn't support the addEventListener method...
    document['on'+fs[0]+'fullscreenchange'] = function(){

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        // check for 'fullscreenElement' to know weither we entered or exited the fullscreen mode
        var status = document[fs[0]+fs[1]+'Element'];

        var statusString =  status ? 'entered':'exited';
        ctx.fillText(statusString+' fullscreen', 250, 50);
        // increment our fullscreen change counter
        fs_count++;
        if(status){
            ctx.fillText('click the canvas to exit fullscreen mode', 150 , 100);
            // attach the exit/cancel fullscreen call
            c.onclick = function(){document[fs[0]+fs[2]+fs[1]]();};
            }
        // log the counters
        ctx.fillText('fullscreen calls : '+fs_count, 0, 140);
        ctx.fillText('resize calls : '+resize_count, 0, 150);
        };

    btn.onclick = function(){
        //this one implies a new camelCase if a vendor prefix is needed...
        var camel = fs[0] ? 'R':'r';
        c[fs[0]+camel+'equest'+fs[1]]();
    };
}
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "red";

var resize_count = 0;
var fs_count = 0;

// increment our resize counter
window.onresize= function(){resize_count++};
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500"></canvas>
<button id="btn">enter fullscreen</button>
```

Since fullscreen requests are blocked in iframes, you can see it in action [**here**](http://jsbin.com/gugubaluxe) and play with the code [here](http://jsbin.com/gugubaluxe/edit?html,js,output)

Also, you will notice that every browser will act differently with this request : webkit browsers will make the page fullscreen but keep the element at the same scale, while FF and IE will scale the element to fit to the new page dimentsions.
This means you shouldn't look to the `getBoundingClientRect()` rect, but rather calculate the new size based on the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` properties.

Comment: The first link at the bottom is broken and the second doesn't open fullscreen, at least in chrome. But I love how the logic works, that is really clever

Comment: @Howzieky yep, this is a temporal link, didn't noticed... I will update the answer but you should be able to open it from the second link by clicking the "open in window mode" link. And it should work from your own page too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from something I created a while ago, it adds the esc key function to exit fullscreen. I hope it works for you as well.

```
$('#view-fullscreen').click(function(){

    $('#container').css({'background': '#000000'}).fullScreen({

        'callback'      : function(fullScreen){
            if ( !fullScreen ) {


                $('#container').css({'background': '#ffffff'});

            }
        }

    });

    $(this).hide();
    return false;


});
```